# Webdav API for NextCloud with Guzzle

Tags: php, multipartform-data, guzzle, nextcloud, content-disposition

I am trying to upload a string (html) to my NextCloud over the Webdav API ([documentation](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/developer_manual/client_apis/WebDAV/basic.html#uploading-files)). I have used multipart file upload, because I read that it is the normal way to achieve file uploads to the API. When I upload a file it properly creates it and I the upload goes through, but it always adds this to the file:

```
----------------------------371289179749834008757921
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

Hello world
----------------------------371289179749834008757921--
```

I just want the "Hello world" part to be put into the file. This is the code I use to upload the string as a file:

```
function sendToNextCloud(string $fileName, string $content)
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $headers = [
            'Authorization' => 'Basic Password',
        ];

        $options = [
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'file',
                    'contents' => $content,
                    'filename' => $fileName,
                    'headers' => [
                        'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'
                    ]
                ]
            ]];

        $request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('PUT', 'nextcloud:8080/remote.php/webdav/' . $fileName, $headers);
        dump($request, $options);
        $res = $client->sendAsync($request, $options)->wait();
        dump($res->getBody()->getContents());
        if ($res->getStatusCode() == 201) {
            dump('Successfully sent');
        }
        return "test";
    }
```

Do I need to alter the content type in the multipart headers, set a different option or use a different way of uploading?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Don't use multipart. The contents of a `PUT` request _become_ the new resource in HTTP and WebDAV. You don't need to wrap the file in something else.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried using postman to make a non multipart upload, but have not found the 'proper way' of doing it. Do you have any resources I can read up on? What do I need to do to just use put and not use multipart?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();
$url = "https://webdav.example.com/file.txt";
$headers = [
    'Content-Type' => 'text/plain',
    'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode('username:password')
];
$contents = "This is the contents of the file";

$response = $client->put($url, [
    'headers' => $headers,
    'body' => $contents
]);

if ($response->getStatusCode() == 201) {
    echo "File uploaded successfully";
} else {
    echo "Failed to upload file";
}
```

This creates a file from a simple string without using multipart and just a simple PUT method.